# How to create CTABLES like SPSS in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, spss, dynamic-tables, expss

[Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VgWo.jpg)

I'm converting a report in SPSS to R. In the final step I need to create a table which looks like this:

I have tried using expss package and I can get table output but I'm not able to create variables having variables inside them in a table.

The SPSS Code for the table is
[Code in SPSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9iuf.png)

Comment: The Count and SUM columns in the Colour categories is if the cases are duplicated or not. If its duplicated it will be in column count and if not then in column sum. I have a varibale in the data set which is 1 if its unique and 0 if its duplicated

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by 'variables having variables inside them'. If it is nesting like 'a > b' then `expss` equivalent is `a %nest% b`.

Comment: Yes it is nesting and I tried it as well but not sure as to implement it correctly as im not getting the output I get in spss

Comment: Please let me know if you figure this out or If you need something else as im still stuck here @GregoryDemin

Comment: It will be very helpful if you provide sample of your data.